# Вывод значения в зависимости от переменной

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Как вывести значение в зависимости от переменной?

Например, я хочу чтобы менялись цифры в зависимости от слова (переменной):

"one" = 1
"five" = 5
"null" = 0.

Comment: Конкретней можно? PHP код хоть какой нибудь или как он должен работать? Что значит "от слова"? Это значение в переменной или её название?

Comment: Я только изучаю php. Слово - значение в переменной.

Comment: Что значит менялись цифры? В другой переменной или как это понимать?

Comment: Имеется ввиду вывод этой переменной. то есть ли значение переменной "one", то на странице отображается "1", если значение переменной "five", то на странице выводится "5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже не знаю понял ли вас полностью. Вот вам пример

```
       <?php

    $foo = array('one','five','null');

    foreach($foo as $value){

        if($value == 'one'){
            echo "1";
        }
        if($value == 'five'){
            echo "5";
        }
//.... 

    }
```

или так

```
<?php

$foo = array( 'one' => 1, 'five' => 5,'null' => 0);

$bar = 'five'; 

echo $foo[$bar];
```

Answer (score 2):

Самая простая реализация как по мне через условные операторы, если 1-2 варианта можно было бы использовать if-else, или сделать в виде массива ваши значения и выводить:

```
$word = 'one';

$list = [
    'one' => 1,
    'five' => 5,
    'null' => 0
];

echo (isset($list[$word]) ? $list[$word] : 0); 
//Вариант для PHP7+
echo ($list[$word] ?? 0);
```